# For what values of a is this process a well defined Ito integral

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

So the question is

For what values of a$\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ is the process

$$Y_{a}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)^{a}dB(s) $$

Well defined as an Ito integral.

By well defined does it mean finite a.s? would it help to look at its expectoration or variance.

Comment: I encourage you to look at the definition of Ito integral under Integration with respect to Brownian motion: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itô_calculus

Comment: i have, just says its  a limit of simple functions, what do i check to see if its well defined or not...

Comment: Oh so it has to have finite $L^{2}$ norm i got $a<1/2$ can it be negative?

Comment: $\int_0^t (t-s)^{2a} ds$ should be finite for all t. You can easily check it is finite iff $a > -1/2$.